Specify caption placement above table in hvfloat
I'm having trouble displaying captions above rotated tables using hvfloat. I've tried all the various package options (capPos=b, t, etc.) and messed around with other settings.
Any suggestions would be welcome!
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, top={1.75in}, bottom={1.5in}, left={1.25in}, right={1.25in}]{geometry}

\usepackage{hvfloat}

\begin{document}

\hvFloat[%
nonFloat=true,%
capWidth=w,%
capPos=t,%
rotAngle=90,%
objectPos=c%
]{table}{%
    \begin{tabular}{l c c c c}
\hline
 & Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 & Column 4 \\
\hline
Row 1               & $0.36 \; (0.10)^{***}$  & $0.35 \; (0.09)^{***}$  & $0.35 \; (0.09)^{***}$  & $0.36 \; (0.09)^{***}$  \\
Row 2               & $-1.32 \; (0.18)^{***}$ & $-1.34 \; (0.18)^{***}$ & $-1.34 \; (0.17)^{***}$ & $-1.31 \; (0.17)^{***}$ \\
Row 3               & $-1.28 \; (0.15)^{***}$ & $-1.27 \; (0.15)^{***}$ & $-1.22 \; (0.15)^{***}$ & $-1.22 \; (0.14)^{***}$ \\
Row 4               & $-0.46 \; (0.13)^{***}$ & $-0.50 \; (0.13)^{***}$ & $-0.49 \; (0.12)^{***}$ & $-0.48 \; (0.12)^{***}$ \\
Row 5               & $0.29 \; (0.09)^{***}$  & $0.32 \; (0.09)^{***}$  & $0.31 \; (0.08)^{***}$  & $0.31 \; (0.08)^{***}$  \\
Row 6               & $0.42 \; (0.16)^{**}$   & $0.46 \; (0.16)^{**}$   & $0.49 \; (0.15)^{**}$   & $0.48 \; (0.15)^{**}$   \\
Row 7               & $1.39 \; (0.19)^{***}$  & $1.41 \; (0.18)^{***}$  & $1.39 \; (0.17)^{***}$  & $1.36 \; (0.17)^{***}$  \\
Row 8               & $0.65 \; (0.12)^{***}$  & $0.64 \; (0.12)^{***}$  & $0.63 \; (0.11)^{***}$  & $0.65 \; (0.11)^{***}$  \\
Row 9               & $0.60 \; (0.14)^{***}$  & $0.58 \; (0.14)^{***}$  & $0.57 \; (0.13)^{***}$  & $0.57 \; (0.13)^{***}$  \\
Row 10              & $1.18 \; (0.25)^{***}$  & $1.20 \; (0.24)^{***}$  & $1.16 \; (0.23)^{***}$  & $1.22 \; (0.23)^{***}$  \\
Row 11              & $2.02 \; (0.11)^{***}$  & $2.01 \; (0.11)^{***}$  & $1.93 \; (0.10)^{***}$  & $1.89 \; (0.10)^{***}$  \\
Row 12              & $-0.23 \; (0.31)$       & $-0.21 \; (0.30)$       & $-0.19 \; (0.28)$       & $-0.21 \; (0.28)$       \\
\hline
Log Likelihood        & $-3020.03$              & $-3173.46$              & $-3272.88$              & $-3343.70$              \\
N (1)             & $8144$                  & $8534$                  & $8755$                  & $8914$                  \\
N (2)    & $4338$                  & $4438$                  & $4477$                  & $4514$                  \\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{l}{Standard errors in parentheses.} \\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\emph{{***}p < 0.001; {**}p < 0.01; {*}p < 0.05}}
\end{tabular}%
}[Table Caption]{Table Caption}{tab:standard-table}

\end{document}


The solution is quite simple: just change capPos=t to capPos=top and you're all set.
However, I think it would be easier and overall better to replace the tabular environment with the tblr environment from the tabularray package. This package supports math mode without any hassle, so you won't need to use $ every time. Additionally, consider replacing \hline with \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule from the booktabs package — it gives a more professional appearance, thanks to precise line thickness and better vertical spacing.
Personally, I would also prefer using the landscape environment from the pdflscape package instead of \hvFloat. The landscape environment rotates the entire page, making the table readable directly in the PDF without needing to rotate your head. Also, using the longtblr environment from the tabularray package provides the possibility to add notes, captions, and other useful built-in features.
Here's my solution:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, top={1.75in}, bottom={1.5in}, left={1.25in}, right={1.25in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtblr}[
    caption={The caption},
    label={tab:standard-table},
    remark{Note}=Standard errors in parentheses.\\$^{***}\mathrm{p} < 0.001; \; ^{**}\mathrm{p} < 0.01; \; ^{*}\mathrm{p} < 0.05$
]{colspec={QQ[r,$]Q[$]Q[r,$]Q[$]Q[r,$]Q[$]Q[r,$]Q[$]}}
\toprule
&\SetCell[c=2]{c}{\textup{Column 1}}&&\SetCell[c=2]{c}{\textup{Column 2}}&&\SetCell[c=2]{c}{\textup{Column 3}}&&\SetCell[c=2]{c}{\textup{Column 4}}&&\\
\midrule
Row 1   & 0.36^{***}  & (0.10) & 0.35^{***}  & (0.09) & 0.35^{***}  & (0.09) & 0.36^{***}  & (0.09) \\
Row 2   & -1.32^{***} & (0.18) & -1.34^{***} & (0.18) & -1.34^{***} & (0.17) & -1.31^{***} & (0.17) \\
Row 3   & -1.28^{***} & (0.15) & -1.27^{***} & (0.15) & -1.22^{***} & (0.15) & -1.22^{***} & (0.14) \\
Row 4   & -0.46^{***} & (0.13) & -0.50^{***} & (0.13) & -0.49^{***} & (0.12) & -0.48^{***} & (0.12) \\
Row 5   & 0.29^{***}  & (0.09) & 0.32^{***}  & (0.09) & 0.31^{***}  & (0.08) & 0.31^{***}  & (0.08) \\
Row 6   & 0.42^{**}  & (0.16)  & 0.46^{**}   & (0.16) & 0.49^{**}   & (0.15) & 0.48^{**}   & (0.15) \\
Row 7   & 1.39^{***} & (0.19)  & 1.41^{***}  & (0.18) & 1.39^{***}  & (0.17) & 1.36^{***}  & (0.17) \\
Row 8   & 0.65^{***} & (0.12)  & 0.64^{***}  & (0.12) & 0.63^{***}  & (0.11) & 0.65^{***}  & (0.11) \\
Row 9   & 0.60^{***} & (0.14)  & 0.58^{***}  & (0.14) & 0.57^{***}  & (0.13) & 0.57^{***}  & (0.13) \\
Row 10  & 1.18^{***} & (0.25)  & 1.20^{***}  & (0.24) & 1.16^{***}  & (0.23) & 1.22^{***}  & (0.23) \\
Row 11  & 2.02^{***} & (0.11)  & 2.01^{***}  & (0.11) & 1.93^{***}  & (0.10) & 1.89^{***}  & (0.10) \\
Row 12  & -0.23 & (0.31) & -0.21 & (0.30) & -0.19 & (0.28) & -0.21  & (0.28) \\
\midrule
Log Likelihood & -3020.03 & & -3173.46 & & -3272.88 & & -3343.70 & \\
N (1)          & 8144 & & 8534 & & 8755 & & 8914 & \\
N (2)          & 4338 & & 4438 & & 4477 & & 4514 & \\
\midrule
Log Likelihood  & -3020.03 & & -3173.46 & & -3272.88 & & -3343.70 & \\
N (1)           & 8144 & & 8534 & & 8755 & & 8914 & \\
N (2)           & 4338 & & 4438 & & 4477 & & 4514 & \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{landscape}



Ah that's an amazing (and very frustrating) solution thanks!
